# Job location is not showing up in the auto-generated email on Simple Job Plugin of Wordpress

Tags: php, email

I am trying to get the Job location into this auto-generated PHP email that gets sent out to the HR department. This is a Wordpress plugin called "Simple Job Board", and a lot of things do reference to custom variables so the variables were created by them. We have three locations, and what I am trying to do is put the job location inside of the email so I can set up rules on the email side so when "XX" location is detected, it will auto-forward it to the correct location. I am not receiving any syntax errors, but the location is not displaying in the email. Here is what this entire section looks like:

```
    /**
     * Admin Email Template
     *
     * @since  2.4.5
     * 
     * @param  int      $post_id                Post ID
     * @param  string   $notification_receiver  Notification Receiver (Admin or HR or || Applicant)
     * @return string   $message                Admin Email Template
     */
    public static function admin_email_template( $post_id, $notification_receiver ) {

        // Applied Job Title
        $job_title = get_the_title($post_id);

        // Applicant Name       
        $applicant_name = self::applicant_details('name', $post_id);
        
        $admin = esc_html__('Admin', 'simple-job-board');

        $message = sprintf( esc_html__('Hi %s', 'simple-job-board'), $admin ) . ',</p>';

        $message .= '<p>' . esc_html__('We just wanted to let you know that someone applied for the', 'simple-job-board') . ' <b>' . esc_attr($job_title) . '</b> ' . esc_html__('position at the', 'simple-job-board') . ' <b>' . esc_attr($job_location) . ' </b> ' . esc_html__('facility. Please head over to wordpress and see your new applicant!', 'simple-job-board') . '</p>';

    
        /**
         * Hook -> Applicant details.
         * 
         * Add applicant's details in notification template.
         *
         * @since  2.2.3   
         * 
         * @param  int     $post_id                Post Id
         * @param  string  $notification_receiver  Notification Receiver 
         * @return string  $message                Message Template          
         */
        $message = apply_filters('sjb_applicant_details_notification', $message, $post_id, $notification_receiver);

        $message .= '<p>' . esc_html__('We will notify you if another applicant applies!', 'simple-job-board') . '</p>'
                . esc_html__('Warm Regards,', 'simple-job-board') . '<br>';

        
        
        /**
         * Modify Admin Email Template
         * 
         * @since  2.4.5   
         * 
         * @param  string  $message                Admin Email Template
         * @param  int     $post_id                Post Id
         * @param  string  $notification_receiver  Notification Receiver                  
         */
        return apply_filters( 'sjb_admin_email_template', $message, $post_id, $notification_receiver );
    }
```

Now the area I am focusing on with this issue is the message itself and the esc_attr($job_location):

```
$message .= '<p>' . esc_html__('We just wanted to let you know that someone applied for the', 'simple-job-board') . ' <b>' . esc_attr($job_title) . '</b> ' . esc_html__('position at the', 'simple-job-board') . ' <b>' . esc_attr($job_location) . ' </b> ' . esc_html__('facility. Please head over to wordpress and see your new applicant!', 'simple-job-board') . '</p>';
```

Any help is appreciated. I already got in contact with the developers of the plugin. However, they didn't provide too much support. Thanks!

EDIT: This is what the main section of the "locations.php" looks like:

```
<!-- Start Job's Location
================================================== -->
<?php if ($job_location = sjb_get_the_job_location()) {
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="job-location"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><?php sjb_the_job_location(); ?></div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<!-- ==================================================
End Job's Location -->
```

Comment: So where is the location supposed to come _from_? Is that something the user selects on the form, is it tied to the current post/page the form gets displayed on, …?

Comment: @CBroe The location comes from a separate php file I believe I've been seeing other files are referencing a "locations.php" so I think that is it.. Those are values we enter on our side, and the user selects from. The $job_location in this case is not where the user is from, but where the job is located at.

Comment: Have you checked what this `sjb_get_the_job_location` function does, and whether it takes any parameters?

Comment: @CBroe I'll double check. I posted the main section of the lcoations.php in the main post

Comment: Found this: 

`function sjb_get_the_job_location($post = NULL) {

        $post = get_post($post);

        if ($post->post_type !== 'jobpost') {
            return;
        }

        $locations = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'jobpost_location'); `

Comment: So, looks like you should be able to use that to get the location, by supplying the post ID.